# How to deal with an 'endless' webpage when scraping

Tags: python, facebook, mechanize, mechanize-python

I'm making a scraper to grab a list of my friends from facebook then scrape a list of mutual friends from them, with goal of constructing a web with the data. I looked at the official facebook api, and it doesn't seem possible to do so I decided to simply scrape from the webpages.

After using mechanize to login, I scraped the page and discovered that facebook only loads 20 friends at a time, loading more as you scroll. I looked through he mechanize docs, but I couldn't find a solution. I tried sleeping for a few seconds before souping the page and that didn't work either.

Not sure where to go from here, is there anyway to emulate scrolling in mechanize?

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow scraping with written permission from them. So use the API.

Comment: I would if I could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you use [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to simulate the actual webpage, you won't be able to simulate "scrolling" (how do you scroll when there is no window, therefore no window height?)

You state that there's nothing in the API which allows you to fetch friends of friends, but there seems to be an [API function](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/friend-list/) that allows fetching the friend list of a user.

If that doesn't work either, your only choice would be to track down the ajax that FB uses to fetch the next list of friends, and use that to fetch more information.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me toward Selenium, I'll try it out. As for the API function, I get this message when trying to fetch friends:    "Only friends who installed this app are returned in API v2.0 and higher. total_count in summary represents the total number of friends, including those who haven't installed the app."

Comment: @AstorThrope feel free to choose my answer if it answered your question.

Comment: I my case I used mechanize in m.facebook.com to get the complete list of friends. Using regex I recognized the url (next) and I navigated page per page getting all the friends, obviously the list that I could see (privileges).